# POST JSON with iron-ajax to SQL Server with Node

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ajax, express, polymer

I am trying to return user data from a login with Polymer.  I have it working with Postman, but am having trouble translating it into Polymer.

In Postman this returns a JSON object, but in Polymer it is returning `undefined`.

Polymer Client Code [Connecting to node.js server]

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxUser"
  url="http://localhost:8080/login"
  method="post"
  handle-as="json"
  content-type="application/json"
  headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}'
  params="[[params]]"
  on-response="saveUserCredentials"
  last-response="{{user}}"></iron-ajax>
```

...

```
<paper-input id="username"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="password"></paper-input>
<paper-button on-tap="loginUser"></paper-button>
```

...

```
loginUser() {
  this.params = {"username": this.$.username.value, "password": this.$.password.value};
  console.log(this.params); // logs this.params as populated JSON 
  let request = this.$.ajaxUser.generateRequest();
  request.completes.then(req => {
    console.log(req);       // logs <iron-request></iron-request>
    console.log(this.user); // logs []
  })
  .catch(rejected => {
    console.log(rejected.request); // not returned
    console.log(rejected.error);   // not returned
  })
}

saveUserCredentials() {
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

Node, Express, mssql Server Code [Connecting to SQL Server database]

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  session.login(req, res)
})
```

...

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config.properties)
    .then(pool => {
      pool.request()
        .input('user', sql.VarChar(50), req.body.username)
        .input('password', sql.VarChar(50), req.body.password)
        .query("SELECT role FROM Login WHERE username = @user AND password = @password")
        .then(response => res.send(response))
        .catch(err => res.send(err))
    })
}
```

Error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 . 
>   at JSON.parse ()
>   at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
>   at parse (C:\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>   at C:\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18 . 
>   at invokeCallback (C:\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>   at done (C:\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>   at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:159:13)
>   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1062:12)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)

Comment: I'm a little suspicious of the way you are constructing this.queryUser.  Why not just construct the object directly?

Comment: Good point.  I updated the question.

Comment: Not immediately obvious.  Can you log the response on the server side before sending?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps post your server-side code then?

Comment: Please check, into function `loginUser()` as console.log(this.$.username.value), You have the values ??

Comment: Yes, it logs JSON.

Comment: @HakanC Server code is now posted.

Comment: When I log ```req``` it seems to be an empty ```iron-request```

Comment: Please change `last-response="[[user]]"` to `last-response="{{user}}"` it is `notify`, `readOnly`  as you will get user data from `iron-ajax` upward data binding.

Comment: That changed the response from ```undefined``` to ```[]```.

Comment: Does ```handle-as="json"``` update the headers to ```"Content-type" "application/json```?

Comment: No, I think the problem is not polymer code, it can't get user data at server side.

Comment: I would concur, but it's working with Postman.

Comment: It seems to me that ```iron-request``` isn't populating correctly.

Comment: If you will feel comfortable, try your desired changes, but I do not think so. But in case if you try to explain your use case, I would comment you another way. For instance, you may use polymer with firebase for database and for much more tools for an app.

Comment: Use case is login and interaction (read/write) to SQL Server DB.

Comment: @KVNA `handle-as="json"` does not set the `Content-Type` header, rather it tells `iron-ajax` to convert the response to a JSON object (via `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`. I recommend examining the request in the DevTools network panel. Check that the `Content-Type` header is set as your server expects (`"application/json"`?). If needed, set that header explicitly (via `<iron-ajax>.headers` or `<iron-ajax>.contentType`).

Comment: @KVNA Logging a custom element (`req` in this case) with `console.log` would yield the element tag itself, as you've discovered. If you want to see all property values of the element, use `console.dir` instead (check the `response` and `status` fields). Or simply: `console.log(req.status, req.response)`.

Comment: @tony19 I'm not understanding the ```<iron-ajax>.headers``` syntax, and am only seeing the ```Content-Type:application/json``` in the Dev Tools response headers.  Can I ```console.log``` the ```iron-ajax``` headers?

Comment: @tony19 I tried ```headers="{'Content-type': 'application/json'}"``` as an ```iron-ajax``` property.

Comment: @KVNA To declaratively bind a JSON object, wrap it with single-quotes (i.e., swap your double-quotes with single-quotes in your example); but it's far simpler to use the `<iron-ajax>.contentType` property in this case: `<iron-ajax content-type="application/json" ...>`.

Comment: OK, I was able to get a server response by setting ```content-type=application/json``` as an ```iron-ajax``` property.  Am now getting Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 as a server side error...  Perhaps this question is resolved and this is a new issue?

Comment: Also, it is now making two requests when I submit.  One with the ```content-type``` set, which resolves to ```200```, and one with that resolves to ```400``` with parsing error.

Comment: And a client side error of ```No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.```

Comment: You probably want to inspect the body of the POST request in your browser devtools to see what your code is actually sending.

Comment: It is sending as far as I can tell and it appears to be valid JSON when I log the params on the client side.  Are the headers case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue appears to be that your server is expecting a JSON object in the request, but the server sees the request as a string due to a missing `Content-Type` header on your request. To set the `Content-Type` for JSON requests, set [`<iron-ajax>.contentType`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax#property-contentType) to `application/json`:

```
<iron-ajax content-type="application/json" ...>
```

> OK, I was able to get a server response by setting content-type=application/json as an iron-ajax property. Am now getting Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 as a server side error...

That sounds like the request is not actually valid JSON (since it contains a `#` as the first character). Use the Chrome DevTools Network Panel to inspect the actual contents of the payload. I wouldn't rely solely on `console.log` in your code.

> Also, it is now making two requests when I submit. One with the content-type set, which resolves to 200, and one with that resolves to 400 with parsing error.

The first message is likely the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), which is sent (as part of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) to the server to check whether `content-type="application/json"` is an allowed header. The second message is the intended data request, but that fails with the following error.

> And a client side error of `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

Your server needs to enable CORS requests. There are various ways to accomplish this, but the simplest Node solution might be to use the [`cors`](https://npmjs.org/package/cors) package:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I updated the question to reflect some of these suggestions, but am still having trouble with the JSON parsing.  Some of the CORS modifications are documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133339/make-cors-request-with-polymer-iron-ajax-and-node-js/

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only outstanding issue is ```Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0``` from ```body-parser``` on the server.  I am still getting a ```No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` error on the client side, but was told that this is being thrown because of the parsing error.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct and open a new issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133936/express-body-parser-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0