# Make CORS Request with Polymer iron-ajax and Node.js

Tags: ajax, express, cors, polymer

I am trying to retrieve data using Polymer and Node, but am struggling to get a valid response back.  I get a pre-flight response error that says the `access-control-allow-origin` is not allowed.

I am running Polymer on `localhost:4001` and Node on `localhost:8080`.

How can I configure either Node or the Client to load a response?

Client

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxUser"
  url="http://localhost:8080/node/api/mssql/login"
  method="post"
  handle-as="json"
  Content-Type="application/json"
  headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}'
  params="[[params]]"
  on-response="saveUserCredentials"
  last-response="{{user}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Node

```
const corsOptions = {
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
}

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions))
```

...

```
app.use((req, res, next) => { // Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, x-api-key")
  next()
})
```

Error

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:8080/login?username=user&password=password:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:4001' is therefore not allowed access. 
>   The response had HTTP status code 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node configuration in the code snippet in the question doesn’t handle `OPTIONS` requests.

To ensure [CORS preflights](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) get handled correctly, consider installing the npm `cors` package:

```
npm install cors
```

And then do something like this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();
app.options('*', cors()); // preflight OPTIONS; put before other routes
```

That’ll handle the preflight response and other CORS aspects without you needing to manually write your own handling from scratch in your application code.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-option has more details on all the options.

Comment: After setting ```const corsOptions = {allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin']}``` and passing it into ```cors()```, I am getting ```Failed to load http://localhost:8080/login?username=username&password=password: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.```

Comment: *The response had HTTP status code 400.* That’s a server error. So it’s not a CORS problem. You’re seeing mention of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  in that message only because the server doesn’t add the additional headers to 4xx error responses (not just the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header but also any other headers you might try to add in your application code).

Comment: So the problem you need to fix is whatever’s causing that `400` internal error on the server side. A `400` error means “Bad Request” and usually indicates that the format of the request payload isn’t what the server is expecting. So in this case I guess either the server isn’t expecting to receive an `application/json` payload or else what your code is POSTing isn’t actually valid JSON. You need to check the server logs to see what information it might be logging on the server side when it sends back that `400` response.

Comment: Yes, I was getting another JSON parse error. ```Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)```... from the ```body-parser``` module.  Although I am not sure how to pipe in a ```console.log``` to the endpoint.

Comment: More context is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131105/post-json-with-iron-ajax-to-sql-server-with-node?noredirect=1#comment83243057_48131105

Comment: OK, it sounds like this answer solves the problem you asked about in the question here — as far as how to get your Node server to handle CORS responses correctly, and in particular how to get it to handle the CORS preflight OPTIONS request. So with that solved, for further help with any other problems you may be running into at this point, you should create separate new questions.