# Polymer npm app running in express static dir causes errors when importing files

Tags: express, es6-modules, polymer-3.x

I have a node application serving API backed and application frontend.
Backed uses Express and static route to serve front end from "views" directory.
The front is a static app using Polymer 3. I am unable to preview the UI when serving it from my backed because of modules resolution. So when I am developing the app I have to use `polymer serve --npm` command. And so for it worked. However now I am working on a part when the API returns data for logged in user. Because both applications (backend and frontend) are in different origins (different ports) the UI won't let me use the API even if I am logged in in backend.

So the question is if there's a way to use polymer's polyserve module in a combination with express router so I can work with both applications on the same port?

Comment: You could run polymer build and install the files produced in the backend

Comment: And execute build command each time anything change? It's impossible to use like that :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that you were talking about development . I believe that the solution would be to set headers with access-control-allow-origin and access-control-allow-headers in your Express installation

Comment: probably helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133489/1926369