# Custom headers blocked by CORS

Tags: express, cors

I am making requests with Angular2+ app to a NodeJS API.

As long as I don't add custom headers, the calls are made and I got a response according to my request. But if I had a header by hand using `interceptor`, it results in an error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [api_url]. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Here is the result of a login method, where I first call the server with no headers, and then add headers and call again the server.

[image]

The headers of the first POST method

[image]

And the one of the second POST method

[image]

The two custom headers are added by an interceptor in Angular as follow

```js
...
const cloned = req.clone({
  headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + idToken)
                      .set("X-QWEMP-data", encrypted)
});
req = cloned
...
```

And when I remove them, the route is reached but, of course, throw error because of the missing data.

Now, for my API, I have tried many configurations to allow custom headers. First was to add headers and return preflight OPTIONS manually as follow (not remember exactly how I did, but it's something like this)

```js
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  set.headers('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
  set.headers('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Authorization,X-QWEMP-data')
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.send()
    return;
  }else{
    next()
    return;
  }
})
```

Then, I used `cors` library and default configuration by just adding `app.use(cors())`

And finally, I have tried adding custom configuration in cors like follow (entire `app.js` file)

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const indexRouter = require('../routes/index');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  methods:'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
  allowedHeaders:'Authorization,X-QWEMP-data,Content-Type,[and all the already accepted headers in case]',
  exposedHeaders:'[same as allowedHeaders]',
  credentials:true,
  preflightContinue:true
})

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(morgan('tiny'));

app.use('/', indexRouter)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000.')
})
```

**EDIT**

Screens of requests in network tab

First OPTION

[image]

First POST

[image]

Second OPTION

[image]

Second POST

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133489/441757 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight. You need to add some form of `app.options('*', cors())` to the server code.

Comment: @alexis, You will note in the cors doc that `app.use(cors())` does not default to handling OPTIONS requests as the default methods are: `"methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",`.  See doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options).

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I have tested with `app.options('*', cors())` before other routes, but doesn't help. @jfriend00, I have added 'OPTIONS' method in cors configuration as you can see on the question.

Comment: I'm confused here.  What you have labelled as First OPTION and First POST succeed.  Those requests are successful.  First OPTION is a 204 status (as expected) and First POST is a 200.  This looks like it works.  I don't know if its reaching the desired server route code, but both requests are getting back successful http responses from the server.

Comment: What you have labeled as Second OPTION seems to work also (204 status).  Second POST appears to never send a response from the server or you're missing something from the screen shot (no status and no response headers).

Comment: That's the problem, as I said on the beginning of my question, as long as I don't add custom headers, everything is ok, but if I add custom header in request using interceptor or anything else, I just can't get a result because of CORS. So here in my method, I make 2 calls to the server, the first one is simple and don't need any custom headers, so everything is fine, but the second needs custom headers and throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not about CORS finally, even if it thrown an error.

In fact, the JWT was too long for not known reason. I used "Burp Suite" to intercept requests and added request in repeater to resend them and test with custom values.

So figuring this out, I needed to update the key used by `jsonwebtoken` library to sign the JWT with a smaller one, and this way, the JWT was smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom header causes the browser to require pre-flight for the cross origin request.  This means the browser will send an OPTIONS request to your server for the same path and it must get back a 2xx response with the appropriate headers from that OPTIONS request or it will not send the actual follow-on request.

From what I can tell in the doc for the CORS module (and verified with a small experiment), when you set:

```
preflightContinue: true
```

You are telling the CORs middleware to skip that OPTIONS request and send it on to other request handlers.  The doc specifically says: *"Pass the CORS preflight response to the next handler"*.  Since you have no other request handlers for that pre-flight request, your server will generate a 404 and the browser will see the pre-flight failed so your request will fail.

So, the first thing to try is to change to:

```
preflightContinue: false
```

If that still doesn't work, then please show the exact request as shown in the network tab of the Chrome debugger.  It will show exactly what the browser is sending for pre-flight and will show exactly what your server is returning in response to that.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't make it work better. In fact I already tried with `false` but I wrote the example with `true`. I have edited the question with the screens you need.