# Express body-parser: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I am trying to return user data from a login with Polymer. I have it working with Postman, but am having trouble translating it into Polymer.

In Postman this returns a JSON object, but in Polymer it is returning undefined.

Polymer Client Code [Connecting to node.js server]

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxUser"
  url="http://localhost:8080/login"
  method="post"
  handle-as="json"
  content-type="application/json"
  headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}'
  params="[[params]]"
  on-response="saveUserCredentials"
  last-response="{{user}}"></iron-ajax>
```

...

```
<paper-input id="username"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="password"></paper-input>
<paper-button on-tap="loginUser"></paper-button>
```

...

```
loginUser() {
  this.params = {"username": this.$.username.value, "password": this.$.password.value};
  console.log(this.params); // logs this.params as populated JSON 
  let request = this.$.ajaxUser.generateRequest();
  request.completes.then(req => {
    console.log(req);       // no log
    console.log(this.user); // no log
  })
}

saveUserCredentials() {
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

Server

```
// Middleware
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions)) // preflight OPTIONS; put before other routes
app.use(formData.parse(formBody))   // parse req.body data from `express-form-data` module
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(apiLimit)                   // Rate limit applied to all requests, can apply to specific endpoints
app.use((req, res, next) => {       // Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, content-type, Accept, Authorization, x-api-key")
  next()
})
```

Error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
>   at JSON.parse ()
>   at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
>   at parse (C:\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>   at C:\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>    at invokeCallback (C:\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>   at done (C:\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>   at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:159:13)
>   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1062:12)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)

[image: Dev Tools]

Comment: That indicates the request contains invalid JSON. Please post a screenshot of the request's payload from the DevTools network panel.

Comment: OK.  I uploaded an image.  The request URL is different because I shortened the string for the question...

Comment: Your request payload keyword got me on the right track.  I needed to add ```this.$.ajaxUser.body = this.params;``` before generating the request.  Thanks Tony!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `POST` body is empty (as seen in the screenshot of your request payload). You're attempting to pass the user credentials via `<iron-ajax>.params`, which is intended to augment the URL query parameters (notice how the request URL contains the user credentials as parameters).

To set the `POST` body, set [`<iron-ajax>.body`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax#property-body) (and change `this.params` to `this.body`) instead:

```
<iron-ajax body="[[body]]" ...>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RxjYRY?editors=1010)

Comment: OK, yes.  This also works and is the more "Polymer" way of doing it.  Thank you!!

Comment: @KVNA No problem :)